# Swift on Xcode - Array index with multiple values

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, indexing

How do I add multiple `Strings` to one index in an `Array`? I had:

```
var cardNamesArray:[String] = ["card5", "card6", "card7", "card8", "card9", "card10", "card11", "card12"]
```

With, card5 at index 0, card6 at index 1, card7 at index 2, and so on. I want to assign card5, card6, card7, and card 8 to index 0, and card 9, card 10, card11, card12 to index 1. Can someone please tell me how to done this?

Is there any way I can do this without making an Array of Arrays and just assigning the cards to the index value?

```
var cardNamesArray:[[String]] = [["card5", "card6", "card7", "card8"], ["card9", "card10", "card11", "card12"]]
```

After making an Array of Arrays, I have only 2 indicies as I need, however I can't seem to call the `String` later on in Xcode. I have a `UIButton` randomizing a number and I want to connect the number to an image represented by one of the cards, but I want four of them to be of the same value.

```
var firstRandomNumber: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))
```

I run into an error on this line saying

> "cannot convert value type '[string]' to specified type 'String'.

```
var firstCardString: String = self.cardNamesArray[firstRandomNumber]
```

However when I put a `[ ]` around `String` in the first line above, it runs and I incur and error on the next line saying

```
self.firstCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: firstCardString)
```

> "cannot convert value type '[string]' to expected argument type 'string'."

I would really appreciate any help! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate random number twice, first one for Array of Array, And second one for your card like this.

```
var cardNamesArray:[[String]] = [["card5", "card6", "card7", "card8"], ["card9", "card10", "card11", "card12"]]
var firstRandomNumber: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))
var secondRandomNumber: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(4))
var firstCardString: String = self.cardNamesArray[firstRandomNumber][secondRandomNumber]
self.firstCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: firstCardString)
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to get string but your object is a Array that you declared before

```
var cardNamesArray:[[String]] = [["card5", "card6", "card7", "card8"], ["card9", "card10", "card11", "card12"]]
```

Change your code to this

```
var firstObjFromArray: Array = self.cardNamesArray[0]
var firstCardString: String = firstObjFromArray[firstRandomNumber]
```